# Does current draw of separate pins of a microcontroller affect each other?

Tags: microcontroller, current, embedded

I have a microcontroller with a IR LED and transistor, as well as a RGB LED. If my battery microcontroller is turning on its RGB LED, connecting to cellular, will this mean less current is going to my IR LED while these processes are occurring, even if they are powered by seperate pins?

The microcontroller I am using is the particle electron.

Comment: In case of LEDs specifically, you can often chose if they should be active high or active low. Before making that decision, you need to check what the MCU pin can source and sink. Some pins can sink more than they can source.

Answer (score 0):

This would happen if you limited the maximum current sourcing capability by putting a resistor in the Vdd line – or the maximum current sinking capability by putting a resistor in the GND line.

Don't do such nonsense. Put the current limiting resistors on the individual I/O pins as needed.

If your battery has a high internal resistance (for example, a button cell), this is the same as the nonsensical resistors in Vdd and GND line.

Answer (score 0):

If you operate the GPIO pins (and the rest of the chip) within its operating conditions, the GPIO's will behave as specified within the operating conditions. There is some margin in those specifications, often expressed as minimum and maximum values, for instance for the voltage drop (below Vcc) for a GPIO pin that is driven high.

If this margin affects your IR LED, its current can indeed vary, due to other GPIO pins, or due to a multitude of other causes. If you can't tolerate such variations, you will have to design your circuit in such a way that the GPIO variantions don't cause a variation in the LED current. One way is to use a transistor, that is driven within saturation for all possible variation in the GPIO voltage.